# Django: Loop over list of objects and save in model with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to use the pycryptodome implementation of [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/protocol/ss.html).

When splitting the shares the output is a list object with tuples of this form:

```
<class 'list'>: [(1, b'\x84\x16H\x92\xaaJ\xf7\x84_\xf9\x02\x03\x86\xff\xb7Z'), (2, b'\x86p\xbe5\xbfP\xe4\x00m\x16\xd3\t\xb3\xc8\xfa\x1f'), (3, b'xR\xecWLY\x15||\xb3\x9c\x0f\xa0\xda>\xa1'), (4, b'\x82\xbdS{\x95d\xc3\x08\x08\xc9q\x1d\xd9\xa6`\x95'), (5, b'|\x9f\x01\x19fm2t\x19l>\x1b\xca\xb4\xa4+')]
```

After `hexlify` in a `for` loop the object is much more readable :

```
for idx, share in shares:
    print ("index #%d: %s" % (idx, hexlify(share)))

index #1: b'84164892aa4af7845ff9020386ffb75a'
index #2: b'8670be35bf50e4006d16d309b3c8fa1f'
index #3: b'7852ec574c59157c7cb39c0fa0da3ea1'
index #4: b'82bd537b9564c30808c9711dd9a66095'
```

I have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    some_other_id = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    encrypted_share = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

I want somehow to filter `MyModel` for a specific `some_other_id` and then for each `user_id` entry save a single share from the list object enrypted with the user's `public_key` taken from the `user_model`.

Here's how I create the shares in my `views.py`:

```
number_of_users = MyModel.objects.filter(some_other_id=self.object.pk).count()
        minimum_shares = (number_of_users*7)//10

        shares = Shamir.split(minimum_shares, number_of_users, key)
```

EDIT:

I'm gonna add some more information to make what I want to achieve more clear.

Basically `MyModel` is a list of users participating in polls.

my `models.py`:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    public_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)

class EligibleVoters(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    encrypted_keypart = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "poll"]
```

Currently I have an `EligibleVoters` table that looks like this:

[image]

I have also created an `RSA` keypair for each `poll`. I want to split the private part of the key pair into shares and save each share next to each user.

So according to the table I posted, for the `poll` with `poll_id=1` I want to filter the users that are allowed to participate in that poll and count them, thus finding out in how many shares I have to split the private key.

I do that with:

```
number_of_shares = EligibleVoters.objects.filter(poll=self.object.pk).count()
```

Next I set the number of the minimum shares needed to reconstruct the key (in my case 70%).

I do that with:

```
minimum_shares = (number_of_shares*7)//10
```

Next I split the key in shares:

```
shares = Shamir.split(minimum_shares, number_of_shares, private_key)
```

As I described before the edit this function gives me a `list` of tuples that contain an index and the shares.

Now I want to save each share next to each user participating in the `poll` with `poll_id=1` (preferably encrypted using the `public_key` of each `user` from my `user_model`).
Ending up with something like this:

[image]

I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to save a MyModel for each user??

Comment: If you want to count users, that way is incorrect. Beacause maybe one user has one or more MyModel.

Comment: I forgot to add that in MyModel `user_id` and `some_other_id` are `unique_together`. So by filtering by a specific `some_other_id` and counting I can count the users.

I'll try and update my question to make what I want more clear.

Comment: Please use onetoone for relation between user and MyModel not foreignkey

Comment: @MohammadAli I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

```
User.objects.filter(poll__id=1)
```

This code give you list of users that their poll id equals 1

You want this?

I cannot imagine your erd, I hope understand your scenario